# Firebase storage, onFinalize function triggered even though permission was denied

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am trying to make an android app with firebase, in which users can only upload when the server approved it.

So, I created firebase storage rules to forbid users from creating files, they are only allowed to update. Then, when uploading is approved, the server creates an empty file users can update.

Now I have the problem that `onFinalize` is triggered even though permission was denied (confirmed in android, task fails with permission denied error).

Should I be verifying in the callback itself that permissions were granted? I find this pretty misleading, or I am doing something wrong...

`storage.rules` :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

    match /jobFiles/{userId}/{jobId} {
      function uploadAuthorized() {
        return request.resource.size < 128 * 1024 * 1024;   
      }
      allow update: if isSignedIn() && uploadAuthorized();
    }
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
exports.jobFile = functions.storage.object()
.onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
    const metadata = object.metadata

    log("File finalized...")
...
});
```

EDIT
Android upload:

```kotlin
        val task = storage
            .child("jobFiles")
            .child(uid)
            .putFile(uri, metadata)

        task
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                ...
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // Permission denied error caught here
            }
```

Exception:
[image: exception]
[image]

Firebase log:

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-jobFile"
>  {"0":"File finalized...","severity":"INFO","message":""}
```

Comment: Can you share how and where you got the permission denied error with the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: I added the exception and stack trace, but to me something is going wrong on the firebase side...

Comment: I would suggest testing the rules with only having allow read, write: if false; and removing others from the rules. In that way it can be determined if security rules are the issue or not. Also I would suggest testing each function, inside the rules, in separation, then add the match, and then add the functions with the && together to isolate the logic. You can make use of [Firebase Rules Simulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator) or [Firebase Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to quickly validate Firebase Security Rules.